# What's wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer

My answer was heavily downvoted and recently deleted.

The 1st version of the answer was incomplete and had a security issue (using eval to make a Regex literal), **but I fixed it.** I explained why the code works, too.

Yes, there are other better-coded answers to the question. However, IMO mine is still good.

Is there something wrong with my code? Are people looking at the revision history to see that the answer used to be bad? What's wrong with my answer, and how can I improve it?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50920268

[image: DELETED ANSWER]

Comment: Given that even *you* think that the other answers are better, why are you surprised that other people agree with you?

Comment: @Servy You shouldn't downvote an answer because others are better. I think my answer is still good.

Comment: Seeing a user write "upvote me plz" for the edit reason is, erm, unique.  Not the kind of click-bait that SO users typically fall for.  You'll get more votes by constantly re-activating the Q+A, just not upvotes :)

Comment: @clickbait You should downvote an answer if it's not useful.  It being an inferior solution to the problem is one way it can be not useful.  Why do you think actively encouraging solutions you think are poor solutions is *useful*?  You don't vote on the *correctness* of an answer, you vote on it's *usefulness*.  An answer being correct, or technically working, but not a good solution, is not a useful answer.

Comment: Huh, fgitw fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no real clear reason as to why this was downvoted so heavily...but if I were to wager a guess:

- The variable names aren't exactly clear as to what their intent is (`bruh` and `gucciGang` aren't descriptive)
- The experts prior  felt like your answer was inferior to the others in both its length and its clarity
- The experts prior may have felt like you were answering a dupe (and dupe downvoting is a thing that happens)
- Ten people [lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248)

Speaking for myself with what JavaScript knowledge I have...I probably wouldn't have downvoted it myself since I don't see your answer being particularly useless, but I probably wouldn't have upvoted since I don't see it being particularly clear, either.

Answer (score 39):

The (now deleted) comments on that answer would seem to indicate some reasons for this:

[image: Screenshot of several comments. A moderator points out the answer is incomplete and doesn't address the questions requirements. Two mods point out it has the XSS vulnerability. Another user says the answerer admits to tactical voting on other answers and a moderator points out they asked for up votes on Reddit.]

as well as this comment on a competing answer:

[image: Dang it! My tactical downvote still wasn't enough to bring this answer down. Written by clickbait.]

Comment: I kind of want to delete my naive attempt at an answer to this question since you were able to clearly and decisively disambiguate the problems.  There are *many* of them.

Comment: The code problems had been fixed. Is it justifiable to downvote an answer only due to tactical downvoting by the answerer?

Comment: @clickbait "tactical downvoting" is a *hostile action* against both the purpose and rules of the site. I.e. you are not upvoting or downvoting the answer on its own merits.

Comment: @clickbait: "*Is it justifiable to downvote an answer only due to tactical downvoting by the answerer?*" Justifiable? No; voting is supposed to be for the post, not the poster. However, when you break the rules, it shouldn't be surprising that others might do so in retaliation. Coupled with the fact that your answer still doesn't really add anything to the Q&A, I don't see a lot of users taking back their downvotes.

Comment: @clickbait After seeing all these comments, I am not sure what did you expect by bringing this to meta? you simply made it worse for you ... too bad I can no more add *my tactical downvote* to your answer :p

Comment: @clickbait is it justifiable that you downvote otherwise good answers in an attempt to bring your own competing answer up? And that you joke about it on top of it? It all seems in bad taste to me....

Comment: He also made an add-on for Firefox for serially downvoting posts and advertised it on Reddit. It might have made him some enemies here.